# Gridview delete/edit not working when using select parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

new to ASP.NET.

I created a sqldatasource and set up basic select query (SELECT * FROM Accounts) using the wizard. I then had the sqldatasource wizard create the INSERT, EDIT and DELETE queries. Connected this datasource to a gridview with EDITING and DELETING enabled. Everything works fine. The SELECT query returns all records and I can edit/delete them.

Now I need to send a parameter to the SELECT command to filter the records to those with the user's id (pulled from Membership.GetUser). When I add this parameter, the SELECT command works fine, but the EDIT/DELETE buttons in the gridview no longer work.

No error is generated. The page refreshes but the records were not updated in the database. I don't understand what is wrong.

CODE:

```
<%
Dim u As MembershipUser
Dim userid As String
u = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name)
userid = u.ProviderUserKey.ToString

SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("UserId").DefaultValue = userid

%>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<Columns>
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="UserId" HeaderText="UserId" 
SortExpression="UserId" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="AccountName" HeaderText="AccountName" 
SortExpression="AccountName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="DateAdded" HeaderText="DateAdded" 
SortExpression="DateAdded" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="LastModified" HeaderText="LastModified" 
SortExpression="LastModified" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CheckingConnectionString %>" 
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Accounts] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Accounts] ([UserId], [AccountName], [DateAdded], [LastModified]) VALUES (@UserId, @AccountName, @DateAdded, @LastModified)" 
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Accounts] WHERE [UserId] = @UserId" 

UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Accounts] SET [UserId] = @UserId, [AccountName] = @AccountName, [DateAdded] = @DateAdded, [LastModified] = @LastModified WHERE [ID] = @ID">
<DeleteParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
</DeleteParameters>
<InsertParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="AccountName" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="DateAdded" Type="DateTime" />
<asp:Parameter Name="LastModified" Type="DateTime" />
</InsertParameters>
<UpdateParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="AccountName" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="DateAdded" Type="DateTime" />
<asp:Parameter Name="LastModified" Type="DateTime" />
<asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>
<SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="UserId"/>
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the Records are still in the DB? And that this is not just that the Grid hasn't done a DataBind after the Edit, Update or Delete?   That has gotten me more than once before!

Also Look at your Code:
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("UserId").DefaultValue = userid

You are setting the SelectParameters... but you need to set the Update, Delete, etc Params too.

Comment: Yes, records are still in the db. Aren't the parameters set for update/delete?. The id used in both of those queries is the id of the particular record. That is also the id in DataKeyNames

Answer (score 0):

Why did you choose to that method .getuser? a simple join using statement in the SQL command line would do the job. You don't need a wizard for that.

Comment: Not sure I understand...the userid is a property of the membership object. Until I pull, I don't know who the logged in user is. Unless I know that I can't retrieve the pertinent records from the Accounts table

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I moved the code pulling the membership provider key to a datasource_selecting event.

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Selecting
    ' Get a reference to the currently logged on user
    Dim currentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()

    ' Determine the currently logged on user's UserId value
    Dim currentUserId As String = currentUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString()

    ' Assign the currently logged on user's UserId to the @UserId parameter
    e.Command.Parameters("@UserId").Value = currentUserId
End Sub
```